# Weapon and Staff Choices in Magicka

Tags: pc, magicka

Does anyone have a list handy of the various items that you can find spread throughout the campaign? A list of their effects would also be appreciated.

Comment: I think a list without effects would be useless, might as well ask for the whole shebang.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Magickapedia](http://www.magickapedia.net/wiki/Items) has a list of items, their locations, and abilities. Here is an excerpt from the list:

#### Staves

- ***Vlad's Gauntlet***
  *Passive ability*
  Inverts damage taken from Life. This makes you take damage from healing spells!

  *Active ability*
  Drains life from the nearest player or creature.

  *Location*
  Chapter 10: Found immediately upon entering Niflheim, right next to the player.
- ***Sceptre of the Troll King***
  *Passive ability*
  Makes enemies less likely to attack the wielder.

  *Active ability*
  Charm target.

  *Location*
  Chapter 9: After the battle with summoned undead soldiers and zombies in the graveyard, head west into the tomb instead of through the locked door you destroyed.

#### Other weapons

- ***M60***
  *Damage type*
  Low Physical

  *Special ability*
  Fast, Ranged. Not affected by Time Warp.

  *Location*
  Chapter 3: Dropped by beastmen with fire protection aura.
- ***Warhammer***
  *Damage type*
  Medium Physical

  *Special ability*
  Pushes target back.

  *Location*
  Chapter 2: On the anvil outside Gram's Workshop just before the crashed goblin airship.
  Chapter 4: On a North leading side path right before the first warlock battle.

Comment: Perhaps consider adding some examples from the list to show if it's useful or not

Comment: I'll count this as the answer, but if anyone makes an answer, like Ivo suggested with a few examples, I'll swap it.

Comment: Sorry! I figured that clicking the link would be sufficient—StackExchange isn't so good for tabular data. I went ahead and added a few examples. Cheers

Comment: m60 is the best item ever.

Answer (score 1):

I am all about the [M60](http://www.magickapedia.net/wiki/M60); doesn't do much melee, if that matters to you, but it's a solid insta-cast beam weapon the rest of the time...Great for mowing down little guys. What's not to like?

Comment: While the M60 is awesome, it doesn't really answer my question